# using like operator in spark sql databricks

Tags: sql, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I'm using spark sql, and I created some Vues to join some data. but I have to join these Vues based on a string column. thats whu I had to use the like operator.

```
  select table.perfume,table2.perfume
  from global_temp.gv_table1 table1
  join global_temp.gv_table2 table2
   on(lower(table1.perfume) like CONCAT('%', lower(table2.perfume), '%') )
```

but the problem with this query it does not not give all the result, example.
there'es a perfume on the table1 called "FlowerBomb" and a perfume on the table2 called "Flowerbomb Eau du parfum", after the join this perfume was not displayed.
is there a problem with the like operator ?

Answer (score 1):

You've got the order of the columns wrong in your `like` expression.

Since `table2.perfume` contains `table1.perfume`, the expression should be like this:

```sql
on(lower(table2.perfume) like CONCAT('%', lower(table1.perfume), '%') )
```

Comment: table 2 hold the longer string value so shouldnt it be like

on(CONCAT('%', lower(table1.perfume), '%') like lower(table2.perfume))

Comment: @NNM No, the [`like`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-like.html) operator looks for the search pattern after `like` not before it.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to convert this to Spark APIs. Its fairly simple -

```
result = table1.alias('1').join(
    table2.alias('2'),
    F.expr("2.perfume like 1.perfume")
)
```